# How to get state vector probabilities in Q#

Tags: quantum-state, programming, q#

Is there a similare function in Q# like Statevector.probabilities in Qiskit to get state vector probability, for example, if my circuit contains one qubit with one $H$ gate, the function returns something like `[0.5, 0.5]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be looking for `DumpMachine` which will gove you all the information about the whole quantum machine including complex amplitudes and phases. You can find the tutorials here : [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/user-guide/using-qsharp/testing-debugging?tabs=tabid-vs2019#dump-functions)